# avconv: remove audio stream, keep audio and video synchronized

Tags: audio, video, avconv

I have an AVI file with one video and three audio streams. I would like to discard two of the audio streams, keeping only one.

I tried to do so using avconv (v11.3-6):

```
avconv -i in.avi -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.avi
```

The problem is that in the resulting file the remaining audio stream is no longer correctly synced to the video stream, though they are synced in the original.

I also tried these variants:

```
avconv -i in.avi -map 0:0 -map 0:2,0:0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.avi

avconv -i in.avi -map 0:0 -map 0:2,0:0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -vsync passthrough out.avi
```

with the same result.

What am I missing?